# Rails render a partial is called to early

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm challenging a annoying problem in rails.

I have a view and I'm trying to render a partial, but only when `@prev_activity != message.about` like this:

```
<%= @prev_activity != message.about ? render(:partial => "dashboards/stream_activity", :locals => { :activity => message.about }) : render(:text => "")  %>
```

In dashboards/_stream_activity.html.erb I render some content and also set previous activity variable:

```
<% @prev_activity = activity %>
```

It does not work because rails render dashboards/_stream_activity.html.erb before `@prev_activity != message.about` is checked, so `@prev_activity` is equal to `message.about`.

Is there any way to solve this one?

Comment: Keep your controller and view code separate! Therefore, you should not set (instance) variables in your renderer(s), it will prevent these kind of problems!

Comment: Are you sure it's problem with Rails and not with your logic in views? Is "dashboards/_stream_activity" really rendered before that line with ?: test? From what you described I see: you render view, then you test condition, logic goes to partial, where (as you described) you change variable which is used in condition and you want to go back condition and not render partial, which in turn would not set variable... That's why time travels are not possible in single universe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally found solution for that. In view where I render the collection I set `@prev_activity` to `nil`.

```
<% @prev_activity = nil %>
<%= render :partial => "dashboards/stream_message", :collection => @workspace_stream.messages %>
```

than it works like expected in dashboards/_stream_message.html.erb:

```
<% if @prev_activity != message.about %>
  <%= render partial: "dashboards/stream_activity", locals: { activity: message.about }%>
<% end %>
```

dashboards/_stream_activity.html.erb:

```
<% @prev_activity = activity %>
```

setting `@prev_activity` to `nil` in controller didn't work as well as all the other solutions posted here.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
 <%= render(:partial => "dashboards/stream_activity",:locals => 
                        { :activity => message.about }) 
                        if @prev_activity != message.about %>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do not use the ternary operator, your problem is likely to go away:

```
<% if @prev_activity != message.about %>
  <%= render(:partial => "dashboards/stream_activity", :locals => { :activity => message.about }) %>
<% else %>
  <%= render(:text => "") %>
<% end %>
```

(It would be nicer to put this functionality in a view helper method)

Comment: it still sets `@prev_activity` to `message.about` first.

Comment: Then you are setting `@prev_activity` somewhere else, certainly not in the partial renderer (unless you are invoking it multiple times)

Comment: Also, read my comment below your question. It really helps you preventing these kind of problems (and debugging them afterwards!)

Answer (score 0):

Keep your variable set code i.e. `<% @prev_activity = activity %>` before a partial call. For example keeping that code in a calling controller and then render partial.
 For example -

```
def myactivity
  // your code
  @prev_activity = activity
  render("dashboards/stream_activity",:locals => { :activity => message.about }) 
  if @prev_activity != message.about
end
```